# How to prevent Excel from handling strings containing a colon as formulas

Tags: excel, csv, ms-office

I am generating csv files, and some cells have the format `nn:nnnn` , i.e. digits separated by a colon. It's not a time format nor a date format, it's just text cells and I don't want them to be re-formatted at all.

I've added some logic to my code in order to identify if it looks like a legal time format or a date, and if so, I wrap that string like this `="nn:nnnn"`. But I'm not interested in adding those characters to all the cells.

It almost solved my problem, but there are still some cases such as `07:1155` that MS Excel insists to translate it as **1.09375**. Other cells such as `68:0062`remain intact. Is there a way to recognize what strings are going to be calculated or translated?

Is there any workaround such as any set-up in MS Excel to tell it not to perform any translation on these kind of text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the following answer from Mr. JP Ronse at the [Microsoft Community forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/how-to-prevent-excel-from-converting-strings/c4533885-88a2-4fdb-babf-02f4ebf1cf9a)

Try to precede a string like 07:1155 with a single quote.
 A single quote prevents Excel from interpreting the value.

For some reason Excel interpret a string like 07:1155 as a time and translates it to the value.
 Excel sees 07:1155 as 7 hours and 1155 minutes, translated to values:

07:00 => 0.291666666666667
 1155 minutes => (1155/60)/24 => 0.802083333333333

The sum is 1.09375

It looks as there is no translation on values like n:00nn or like n:0nnnnn

Checking on the 2 n's after the colon (not 00) could be a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just opening your CSV in Excel, you might try doing (Menus) Data/Get External Data/From Text. Or if you're using VBA, that would be something like:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;H:\csvtest.csv" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$3"))
    .Name = "csvtest_1"
    .FieldNames = True
   etc
End With
```

You may need to specify Text as the incoming column format.

Comment: I'm not using VBA. I create a flat .csv file with comma delimited columns and then browse it in IE. But even if I try to type in this cell 07:1155 Excel converts it to 1.09375