# Convert Time Values (In-Cell) to Minutes - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to take the values of time passed (formatted HH:MM:SS) and convert it to just minutes.

The issue I am having is that when I try and get the value of the time-value cell, it converts it to some odd value.

Example:

Wrong Value (what Excel gives me now, in worksheet):
`34:32:12` = `1.43902777777778`

Right Value (what Excel should give me):
`34:32:12` = `2072.2`

Calcualted:

34*60 + 32 + 12/60

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763097/how-to-prevent-excel-from-handling-strings-containing-a-colon-as-formulas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your source value is in cell A1, here is all you need:

```
=N(A1*1440)
```

This method does not require a reformatting of the output cell.

How does it work?

Dates and times are stored in Excel as a combined number... where the integer portion represents the number of days since December 31, 1899 (although the year that Excel calculates from can be changed to 1904 in the *Excel Options*, but that is immaterial).

The decimal portion of the stored number represents the time component to associate with the date.

Your value of `1.43902777777778` is correct. It states that the ~34.5 hours represents ~1.44 *days*.

Since you are interested in minutes, we convert that *days* figure to minutes by multiplying by 1440 as there are 1440 minutes in a day.

The N() function that wraps that calculation ensures that the displayed output is treated as numeric by Excel. Otherwise the output cell would adopt the date-formatting of A1.

Comment: Good edit by the way - I was just about to ask how the functions calculates everything. Very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Either format the cell as [m] to see 2072, or multiply by 1440 (the number of minutes in a day) and format as 0.0 to see 2072.2